# Handling large integer on C/C++ using Visual C++ 2008

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, biginteger

How do I do to handles some big positive integers (like 9,999,999,999) on Visual C++ 2008 on a 32-bit PC.
Please give an example on declaring, printf, scanf of these big positive integers.
Please consider using 9,999,999,999 in your example.

Comment: that sounds like a homework to me..

Comment: How big will your numbers be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned long long foo;
scanf("%llu", &foo);
printf("%llu", foo);
```

Comment: That should be `%lld`, since you have declared it as signed rather than unsigned.

Comment: Thanks, changed foo's definition to unsigned, since the question stated that the numbers were positive